# IPv4 address dot in square brackets

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, ipv4

I have been asked to block IP address of the form:

```
1.111.1[.]111
```

I have never come across a dot in square brackets in IPv4.
Does it have any meaning or interpretation?

Comment: That is not a valid IP V4 address. Either some typo or some strange attenpt to suggest a regular expression. Just forget it.

Comment: It _could_ be that the author tried to express a 24bit network mask. That is usually noted as `1.111.1.111/24`. Which also is not a valid address, it is not meant to be. It is an agreed upon notation.

Comment: I double down this question. Threat intel bois always go like xx[.]xx[.]xx[.]xx and I also don't know why. Found this question while searching it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some valuable information on the topic can be found at [Advanced Indicator of Compromise (IOC) extractor](https://inquest.readthedocs.io/projects/iocextract/en/latest/):

> It is common practice for malware analysts or endpoint software to “defang” IOCs such as URLs and IP addresses, in order to prevent accidental exposure to live malicious content. Being able to extract and aggregate these IOCs is often valuable for analysts. Unfortunately, existing “IOC extraction” tools often pass right by them, as they are not caught by standard regex.
>
> For example, the simple defanging technique of surrounding periods with brackets:
>
> ```
> 127[.]0[.]0[.]1
> ```
>
> Existing tools that use a simple IP address regex will ignore this IOC entirely.

To summarize, this notation make links/ip impossible to click or use "by error" in order to mitigate the risks linked to those Indicators Of Compromise.